# Apply rotation and translation to bones

Tags: python, blender

Edit*
I asked the question on blender.stackexchange.com.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/58524/27834

---

I'm using blender 2.49 because the script was originally written for that version.

I'm trying to create animations using some transform data.

The original data contains a sequence of joints. Each joint has its own rotation and translation values, it may or may not have a parent joint. This sounds pretty much like bones in blender, right?

**To set up the skeleton:**

```
#pseudocode
for joint in joints:
    v = Vector(0,0,0)
    j=joint
    while j:
        v = j.rotation*v
        v = v + j.location
        j = j.parent
    joint.position = v
```

**To process a certain frame:**

```
#pseudocode
for joint in joints:
    v = Vector(0,0,0)
    j=joint
    while j:
        rot=j.rotation+j.curFrame.dRotation
        loc=j.location+j.curFrame.dLocation
        v = rot*v
        v = v + loc
        j = j.parent
    joint.position = v
```

---

To make things simple, I convert each joint into a small bone.

```
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        bone = Blender.Armature.Editbone()
        bone.head = Mathutils.Vector(0,0,0)
        bone.tail = Mathutils.Vector(0,1,0)
        bone.name = 'Bone.' + str(i)
        bone.parent = armature.bones['Bone.' + str(bones[i].parent)]
        armature.bones[bone.name] = bone
```

Then I move the bones to their desired locations, using the posebone trick to create the skeleton:

```
    pose=armObject.getPose()
    pose_bones=pose.bones
    #pose the bones
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        tran = transforms[i]
        pose.bones[name].quat = Mathutils.Euler(tran.rotX,tran.rotY,tran.rotZ).toQuat()
        pose.bones[name].loc = Mathutils.Vector(tran.locX, tran.locY, tran.locZ)
    pose.update()
    #update editbones
    armature.makeEditable()
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        armature.bones[name].matrix = pose.bones[name].poseMatrix
    armature.update()
    #reset pose
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        pose.bones[name].quat = Mathutils.Euler(0,0,0).toQuat()
        pose.bones[name].loc = Mathutils.Vector(0,0,0)
    pose.update()
```

So far so good. But when I apply the transform to a certain frame, the results are incorrect.

```
    for i in range(0, len(bones)):
        name = 'Bone.'+str(i)
        tran = frame.dTransforms[i]
        pose.bones[name].quat = Mathutils.Euler(tran.rotX,tran.rotY,tran.rotZ).toQuat()
        pose.bones[name].loc = Mathutils.Vector(tran.locX, tran.locY, tran.locZ)
```

By incorrect I mean the rotations seem correct, but the translations are all wrong. I guess it is because the transforms should be applied to the posebone's local space(the skeleton is correct because all transforms start from the center )? But how do I do that?

Comment: Most likely it is because the head of a bone is fixed to the tail of it's parent preventing it from moving. To get a bone to move try moving the parent's tail. Maybe try first without parenting the bones, the length of bones may need adjusting. You will get more help if you use a newer blender version and you can find blender specific help at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Mostly likely I did the math wrongly, but I don't know exactly what went wrong(so blender version doesn't really matter). Bone parent doesn't prevent it from moving if the bone is created in that way(no IK, no constraint), actually I can edit the transform values in pose mode and the values match those in the code.

Comment: There is a connected property that locks the head to the parents tail. In 2.77 you can alter the bones location properties while in pose mode but the bone doesn't visually move if it is connected.

Comment: @sambler I asked the question on blender.stackexchange, thank you for pointing me the right direction. As for the connected property, I have already double checked by manually inputing the loc values in pose mode. The bones moved normally(though the results were still wrong).